# HighStock "xRange" chart is not working with older version library(HighStock)

Tags: javascript, highcharts, dotnethighcharts

I have implemented xRange chart with latest HighStock library (Highstock JS v6.1.1) and it works absolutely fine but in my project we are using ***older version*** of library as  ("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highstock/2.1.7/highstock-all.js") and that does not work.

**Note:** I don't want to upgrade the library since it will have major impact on other existing charts.

My xRange chart **working** fiddle here: [please refer](http://jsfiddle.net/jdhpuov1/186)

xRange chart with Older version of library **NOT working** fiddle here: [please refer](http://jsfiddle.net/jdhpuov1/188)

Can anyone please help. Thanks

---

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highstock/2.1.7/highstock-all.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/xrange.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
```

---

```
Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'xrange'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Admission Timeline'
    },    
    xAxis: {
       type: 'datetime',
       min: Date.UTC(2017, 6, 17, 16, 00), 
       max: new Date().getTime()      
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Admission'
        },
        id:'123445567',
        categories: ['Admission'],
        reversed: true,
        opposite: false,
        labels: {
                 x: -3,
                 align: "right", 
                 style: {
                           color: "#595959",
                           font: "13px Calibri, sans-serif"
                      }
         },
         title: {           
                        text: "",
                        textAlign: "right",
                        rotation: 0,
                        margin: 60,
                        style: {
                            color: "rgb(124, 97, 114)",
                            font: "15px Calibri, sans-serif",
                            fontWeight: "bold"
                        }
         },
         offset: 0,
         lineWidth: 0,
         timeline: true
    },
    tooltip: {
            split: false,
        formatter () {
          const x1 = Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d', this.x)
          const x2 = Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d', this.x2)
          const header = `<span style="font-size:10px">${x1} - ${x2}</span><table>`   
          const body = `<tr>
                  <td style="color:${"#FF0000"};padding:0">${this.series.name} </td>
            </tr><tr>
                  <td style="color:${"#808000"};padding:0"><b>Disease: Allergy</b></td>
            </tr>`      
          const footer = '</table>'      
          return header + body + footer
    },
    useHTML: true
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Name: XYZ',        
        data: [{
            x: 1504310400000,
            x2: 1506124800000,
            y: 0,            
            partialFill: 0.20,
            color: "#00FF00"
        },{
            x: Date.UTC(2017, 09, 04),
            x2: Date.UTC(2017, 09, 30),
            y: 0,           
            partialFill: 0.05
        },{
            x: Date.UTC(2017, 11, 14),
            x2: Date.UTC(2017, 11, 24),
            y: 0,           
            partialFill: 0.05,
            color: "#E77471"
        },{
            x: Date.UTC(2018, 01, 05),
            x2: Date.UTC(2018, 01, 21),
            y: 0,           
            partialFill: 0.02
        }] ,                
        yAxis: 0,       
                title: "series Title", 
        color:'gray',            
        borderColor: 'gray',
        pointWidth: 20,       
        timeline: true,
        type: "xrange",           
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            x: 1,
            y: 24,
            borderWidth: 2,
            padding: 5,
            shadow: false,
            style: {
                 fontFamily: "Calibri",
                 color: "#FFFFFF",
                 textShadow: "none",
                 fontSize: "11px",
                 fontWeight: "normal",
                 cursor: "default"
            }
        }
    }]
});
```

Comment: The xRange type was not available under v2. You are trying to mix v2 highstock library with latest v6x modules. That is not going to work. Suggest that you upgrade your highstock.

Comment: Not sure what you're looking for here. The answer is to update your version. It's understandable that you are not prepared to do that if it is disruptive, but - it's still the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback guys but not sure why this question is down voted.???

Answer (score 4):

Without some serious modification to your highstock.js, you will probably not be able to make `xRange` work with Highstock pre 6.0.0, as that is when support for `xRange` was added. You can see this in the [changelog](https://www.highcharts.com/documentation/changelog)(under 6.0.0), and in the [plotOptions](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series) where it denotes the version something was added, in the top right corner of that element(if you scroll down to the bottom, you will see it says **Since 6.0.0** on `xRange`).

Comment: Thank you for your valuable feedback.